# Dot notation for "member" of a mathematical "object"

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, inverse-function

I am trying to write the Reflective Property of Inverse Functions in mathematical notation based on this description:

*The graph of $f$ contains the point $(a,b)$ if and only if the graph of $f^{-1}$ contains the point $(b,a)$.*

Because the definition mentions "the graph of (a function)", I wish to use some notation to express the graph of a function. On Wikipedia's [Graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function#Definition), the notation used is $G(f)$.

I would then write:

$(a,b)\in G(f) \iff (b, a) \in G(f^{-1})$

However, as a programmer, I would rather use "dot notation", since I think of a function as a mathematical "object" with "members" (object-oriented programming concepts). These members, in my mind, are the domain $f.X$, the codomain $f.Y$, and the graph $f.G$. (The definition of a function as domain X, codomain Y, and graph G can be found in Wikipedia's [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition).)

With dot notation, I would write:

$(a,b)\in f.G \iff (b, a) \in f^{-1}.G$

Is there any precedent/examples for dot notation to "access" a "member" of an "object" in math? Is the idea of a mathematical object common? (I see Wikipedia's list of [mathematical objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object), but it is a very short article.)

Comment: While dot notation is common in OOP, functional programming frequently uses notation like $G(f)$, as well as alternatives such as pipe operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't make up new notation for something that's well established.  You'll only confuse people.  "Dot notation" is not generally used in mathematics, and in particular $f . X$ and $f . Y$ are going to be extremely confusing: while one sometimes has functions whose domain and codomain are $X$ and $Y$, those letters are not in any way reserved for the general notion of domain and codomain.

Comment: That sounds quite reasonable. However, I find the notation G(f) equally confusing. Is there an intuitive meaning behind the expression G(f)? That looks the same as function notation, and it seems strange to me to use a "function" which maps functions to graphs. G: function --> graph

Comment: The dot is already used for the dot product. In mathematics, I would say the equivalent of the dot in programming, is to put as an index. And actually objects in computer science are just in some sense more advanced tables, which mathematically are sequences.

Comment: @AdrianSelf It is function notation.  And why shouldn't functions map functions to graphs?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. It was just strange to see a function needed to identify an inherent property of its input. However, this happens all the time, like im(z) returning the imaginary part of z, when z could be defined as a real part and an imaginary part. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianSelf "to see a function needed to identify an inherent property of its input" That's completely normal in some functional programming languages like Haskell. From a mathematical perspective, it would be weird to use a different syntax for those mathematical functions that *happen* to pick out parts of something.